# Expand scope in answer or stick to scope limitation of original question?

Tags: discussion, answers

In ["How fast are transfers between the C64 and the 1541 floppy drive?"](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14061/7208) the OP describes an application that needs fairly fast transfers between the C64 and an attached drive, and this application probably also wants to minimize the amount of CPU time it spends on transfers on the C64 side. (The application is to have the drive do co-processing, so each cycle used for communication on the C64 side directly reduces the advantage to be gotten from this coprocessing.)

He mainly discusses using the KERNAL routines, however, and his last sentence is:

> If I use the KERNAL routines, what kinds of speeds can I anticipate?

There are a couple of other options for faster and cheaper (in cycles) communication that would suit this application, but both involve not using the KERNAL. For an answer giving an overview of these, is it is better to put the answer on this question or to write a new question explicitly asking about that and put the answer on that new question?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a separate question so that various possible answers to each can be demarcated clearly.

I would though edit each of the questions, Kernal / non-Kernal, to have links to each other with a note explaining this demarcation.

Answer (score 3):

I am the OP of the question you're talking about, and I concur with Chenmunka. <del>I look forward to reading the new question!</del> Actually I went ahead and [wrote it.](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/what-are-my-options-for-fast-bidirectional-transfer-between-a-c64-and-a-1541)

Answer (score -1):

Separate questions are usually the better way as they allow to tackle each issue / view more clear and direct, making the (hopeful great) answers to each on their own, sparing the reader to invest time to differentiate again.

Modifications to questions should y default help to narrow it down, helping to form a clear answer to a clear problem, making the result long term useful.

Widening it up will move a question always toward the 'too broad' category, one that does not fit the basic format at all.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your implication that the "basic format" is restricted to narrow questions useful only to those who already have a general undertstanding of older computer systems. While that may be fine for SO, where there are many other resources for "how do I program?" questions, there are few, if any, "retrocomputing boot camps," classes or tutorials, and therefore having a set of general questions that can help people get to the point where they can start asking good questions is a very useful resource. This site should not be just for those who are already experts.